# WSO2 ESB: Get Address Endpoint URI from registry

Tags: wso2

I want to define my URL in the registry so that I can change it between environments without having to redeploy CAR files. I have done this successfully in the past for HTTP Endpoints, but with Address Endpoints, I cannot get it to work.

How I normally would do it, is to declare the property in the API.xml file:

```
<property name="uri.var.my_EP" expression="get-property('registry', 'gov:/integration/endpoints/myapp/my_EP')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Then I simply replace the hard-coded URI with my property in the endpoint.xml file:

```
<http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.my_EP}">
```

If I do the following on the Address Endpoint, I get a "The system cannot infer the transport information from the {uri.var.my_EP}" error:

```
<address uri="{uri.var.my_EP}">
```

What/how must I do to define the URI for Address Endpoints in the registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have properly stored in registry, you can use endpoint directly like below:

`<endpoint key="gov:/integration/endpoints/myapp/my_EP"/>`

Personally, for endpoints i use `conf:/..` repository.

Comment: problem doing like that is you cannot specify additional attributes such as timeout, etc.

Comment: Yes you can. You store in registry whole  address endpoint / http endpoint definition, with timeout, markForSuspension also with custom properties and so on.  Unless you're using some old version wso2

Comment: You are correct, had a brain-fart there for a moment...